# Como obter o diretório do local onde um arquivo .py está sendo executado?

Tags: python, python-3.x, diretório

Tenho um arquivo .py de setup, por isso cada vez que ele for executado eu preciso saber o diretório de onde ele está sendo executado, como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes obter o directório atual do script usando:

```
import os
print(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

[Referência ao stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9350788/1473534)

Answer (score 2):

Para obter o caminho absoluto:

```
import os 
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

Para obter o caminho relativo:

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
```

Comment: A diferença não é bem essa: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322836/how-do-i-find-directory-of-the-python-running-script-from-inside-the-script/19323023#19323023, https://repl.it/repls/IntrepidOrderlyFlicker

Comment: "cwd" é "current working directory" - e não tem a ver com o diretorio onde o arquivo está, e sim, o diretório de onde o programa foi chamado para ser executado.